# Borders not adjusting to Bootstrap grid columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Here an image that shows the problem:
[image]

As you see, at the top left there is a column. The right content wraps at 2 places at the same time: It wraps at the right of the column and it continues at the bottom of it. That's ok, and that's the reason I did not asign any col-class, like col-md-8 to it (otherwise it would be positioned either at the right or at the bottom of the column at the top left - not on 2 places at the same time. My bootstrap column code for the left column is: `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">`.

Problem: The bootstrap grid makes the content wrap correctly around the left column, but the border goes its own way, right over the left column. How to let the Bootstrap grid columns work not only for contents, but also for borders?

Intention:
The borders need to follow the content like this and wrap around the left column:
[image]

These are the codes for the div that gives it a red border. As said above, the contents around the left column has no column asigned to it, but only this:

```
<div style="border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#800000;">
```

Comment: Can you please Update your code in fiddle

Comment: Atleast you should write the code what you have tried

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your reaction. Not meant bad, but it are just lines of text. Whether the text says "Hello this is the text and I am on this line". or "Blablabla blablabla blablabla" doesn't make any difference, is it? The only codes that show the properties of the several blocks ot text are displayed in my question. I like to keep it short. If something is not clear, I appreciate any comments.